# Edit system extensions in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I am using the felogin system extensions. Those extensions are part of the default TYPO3 installation and they are stored in typo3/sysext. I know that I can edit them by editing its code directly but I guess it is not the best way of doing it.

How can I "overwrite" those extensions without changing their code?

Shall I create a new custom plugin and copy & paste code of a system plugin I wish to alter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just modify the extension and place a copy in typo3conf/ext/. This directory (so called "local extensions") override the system extensions.

However, you will probably run into trouble when you want to upgrade TYPO3.

Did you find a bug, if so, please [report](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-core/issues/new) it. If you know, how to fix, then it would be great, if you would [push the change into the review system](http://wiki.typo3.org/Contribution_Walkthrough_Tutorials)

If you just want to change functionality, modifying existing code is not a really could solution. There's the concept of hooks (which is a clean one) and of XLCASSes, which is somehow dirty (as it can also cause trouble with newer TYPO3 versions). So basically the same as with every other extension.

Steffen

Comment: In this case, I think that the hook method is the most appropriate approach.